# Forgot pattern. Phone locked

Tags: probability, combinations, pattern-recognition

I forgot my pattern of my phone. I have few points which I remember about the pattern. Can you help me find the list of possible combinations of patterns for trying and unlocking.

The keypad is as below.

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Hints:

1. I have not used 1, 4 and 7 for drawing the pattern, therefore left with only 6 numbers.
2. The pattern is only of 4 numbers / lines. So patterns having 5-9 lines are not relevant.
3. Starting point / number is 2 or 3. So, patterns starting from 5, 6, 8, 9 is not relevant

That's all I remember. Please help. I do not want to do factory reset an lose all my data.

Regards. Arjun M K

Comment: There are still way too many possible patterns to try out to be guaranteed finding the right one before the phone locks down.

Comment: GOTO service center.

Comment: Is this a problem, er, mathematical?

Comment: @StubbornAtom What are the chances of that? ;)

Comment: @StubbornAtom If it was stated in the third person, it would a problem that sounds like a awful teacher's math exam.  Pretty much like all those leaking bathtub problems...

Comment: This leaves just $2 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 = 432$ posible patternsYou should just do the reset and use your backup. You do have a backup, don't you? (If this is an iPhone, you might have done a backup automaticly when pluging it into your computer or via iCloud backup)

Comment: You should say how many digits are in the pattern. Another useful piece of info is whether digits are used only once.

Comment: is that a genuine question ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's 4 digits and every digit only appear once there are $2\cdot 5\cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 120$ combinations - Selection for the first digit is $2$ possible ways, then pick the next from the remaining $5$ digits, the third from the remaining $4$ digits and the last from the remaining $3$ digits.